# Python plotly: Dates in other languages

Tags: python, date, graph, plotly

I've inserted a dataset in plotly in order to plot a time-series graph. Plotly converted it into a datetime object adequately but the display is in english and I need it to be in spanish. Can I do that? How?

Here's the code:

```py
trace1 = Scatter(
  x=['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02'],
  y=['14.7414', '14.7414'],
  name='Precio del dlar',
  error_y=ErrorY(
    color='rgb(0,116,217)',
    thickness=1, width=1
  ),
  error_x=ErrorX(
    copy_ystyle=True
  ),
  marker=Marker(
    color='rgb(0,116,217)',
    size=8,
    symbol='circle'
  ),
  line=Line(
    color='rgb(0,116,217)',
    width=2
  ),
  xsrc='rafaeles:2294:78082d',
  ysrc='rafaeles:2294:7b41b5'
)
```

The date format that I inserted is x. Plotly coded it as Jan 15, but I need that to be in spanish.

Comment: trace1 = Scatter(
    x=['2015-01-01', '2015-01-02'],
    y=['14.7414', '14.7414'],
    name='Precio del dlar',
    error_y=ErrorY(
        color='rgb(0,116,217)',
        thickness=1,
        width=1
    ),
    error_x=ErrorX(
        copy_ystyle=True
    ),
    marker=Marker(
        color='rgb(0,116,217)',
        size=8,
        symbol='circle'
    ),
    line=Line(
        color='rgb(0,116,217)',
        width=2
    ),
    xsrc='rafaeles:2294:78082d',
    ysrc='rafaeles:2294:7b41b5'
)

The date format that I inserted is x. Plotly coded it as Jan 15 on, but I need that to be in spanish.

Comment: Edit into your question not as a comment, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but maybe it might be useful for someone with the same problem than Rafael and me. I had this problem and I asked to the Plotly Community about [how I can change the date language](https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-change-date-language/34958) and the answers has been really helpful.

Note that I edited your question to insert your code in a code block to ease the reading of it.

First of all try to check what is your current locale settings with the `locale` module of Python:

```py
import locale
locale.getlocale()
```

If you get something different than the one you want to use, you can set the one you want for dates and time with `locale.setlocale()`. For example:

```py
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES')
```

You can test this new locale works fine testing it with the `datetime` module as follows:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.now()

datetime.datetime(2020, 2, 14, 10, 33, 56, 487228)

today.strftime('%A %d de %B, %Y')

'viernes 14 de febrero, 2020'
```

Then you can try to reformat your data using `datetime` and `strftime`. In your case it might be something similar to:

```py
dates = [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1).strftime('%A %d de %B, %Y'),
         datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 2).strftime('%A %d de %B, %Y')]
```

This works for me on iPython:

```
In [1]: import locale                                                                                                                                  

In [2]: locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "es_ES.utf8")                                                                                                 
Out[2]: 'es_ES.utf8'

In [3]: import datetime                                                                                                                                

In [4]: dates = [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1).strftime('%A %d de %B, %Y'), 
   ...:          datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 2).strftime('%A %d de %B, %Y')]                                                                            

In [5]: dates                                                                                                                                          
Out[5]: ['jueves 01 de enero, 2015', 'viernes 02 de enero, 2015']
```

Then if you want to use it in `x` axis, you can call `dates` inside `x`:

```py
trace1 = Scatter(
  x=dates,
  y=['14.7414', '14.7414'],
  ...
)
```

It works for me! And I hope it works for you too.

If you need a different format for the date I recommend you to read the [documentation about date-time microformats of D3](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md#format). I also recommend you to read the thread [How to change date language?](https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-change-date-language/34958) I opened on Plotly Community Forum, because the answers are very useful and are the ones which helped me to solve my issue and to answer this question. You can also check [this notebook](https://plot.ly/~empet/15517/how-to-display-ticklabels-as-d/) shared in the thread, in which one of the users who answer me show how to solve the issue if you are using a `pandas` dataframe.

Excuse me for a lot of this stuff I am linking, but it might be very useful too to read about the [methods to update axis](https://plot.ly/python/creating-and-updating-figures/#the-update-axis-methods) in Plotly documentation, because you can update the format of the axis you want with as follows:

```py
fig.update_xaxes(tickformat='%d-%b-%Y')
```

I want to credit to **empet** and **eliasdabbas**, users of the Plotly Community, for their answers!

Answer (score 0):

In [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69578922/865169) it does not really work to convert the time axis to a text label axis.
As of version 5.14, what you can do instead is to manipulate the axis labels generated by Plotly by using the `labelalias` property. You can see [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77216202/865169) for a tiny example how.