# Format x-axis with datetime values showing the day names in spanish

Tags: python, datetime, plotly, axis-labels, plotly-python

I have a series of data on the weather. In this case only the temperature for 14 days.

Plotly does very well managing dates automatically natively but I can't change the language of the dates and setting the python locale with `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES')` doesn't affect Plotly's dates:

[image]

For them to appear in Spanish I have to format each datetime with `datetime.strftime()` but then plotly treats them as strings and very ugly things come out:

[image]

Additionally, the data density at the end is lower and in this second way (with strings) plotly crushes the graph since it does not know the real distance between dates.

I also can't find a way to center the X axis labels to the center like in the first example.

**I would like to have something like this (I drew it):**
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/tree/master/dist#to-include-localization definately supported.  looking in how to use this in python

Answer (score 2):

A similar question has been posted to the plotly [community](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-change-date-language/34958/4) with a way to deal with it. I have converted the original data to pandas date format and then changed the locale. I also have a different locale so I created a code to try it out. It was correctly displayed in Spanish. I wanted to post the resulting graph, but some of the text was garbled, so I won't post the image. x-axis ticks to the side can be set by the angle of the ticks, as shown in the code.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_ES') 

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':pd.date_range('2021-09-01','2021-09-30'), 'value':np.random.randint(0,10,(30))})
es_date =  pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
es_date = [d.strftime('%d %A') for d in es_date]
df['es_date'] = es_date

fig = px.line(df[:10], x='es_date', y="value")

fig.update_xaxes(tickangle=0)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Yep, I saw that post of the plotly community and I understand your example but it isnt that i need. I need plot all the datetimes but only show in x-axis one label for day.

For example: 24 hour values in day named "Lunes 07" only must show "Lunes 07" in all the period and one time, no "Lunes 07, Lunes 07, Lunes 07, Lunes 07 ..."

Comment: There are two requirements in your question: the first is that the x-axis ticks be written in Spanish. Has that been accomplished?　The second is to have the tick marks parallel to the x-axis. Have you achieved that? We are limiting the date format to the day of the week and the day of the week, so depending on the amount of data you want to display, the day of the week and the day of the week will be repeated because the month and year are omitted. It is said in the comments that that notation should be shown only once, but please update the question or indicate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced exactly the same problem as you where I needed to plot data with a time axis in Danish.
As of version 5.14, it is also possible to manipulate the axis labels by using the `labelalias` property. Based on the [Plotly documentation](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#specifying-label-aliases), this should do the trick in your case (if I assume your data is in a DataFrame `df`):

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(df, x="Fecha")
fig.update_xaxes(labelalias={"Tuesday 05": "Martes 05", "Wednesday 06": "Miércoles 06"})

fig.show()
```

I do not speak Spanish, so I have just looked up the day names. I have only entered the first two of your labels, but the principle is to add all of the necessary translations.
One nice detail is that it does not matter if you generate too many label translations in that dictionary; unnecessary entries will just remain unused. Then of course, the hard work may lie in generating all the relevant label/translation pairs.