# python-plotly date formatting with respect to locale

Tags: python, localization, plotly, plotly-python

I'm using the python `plotly` lib to plot some timeseries. The problem I have is that somehow plotly doesn't honor my locale setting.
See the following code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
from datetime import datetime
import locale


#Get information on the actual locale setting:
print(locale.getlocale())


#Set locale for another country:
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE.UTF-8') # this sets the date time formats to Germany; there are many other options for currency, numbers etc. 
#for any other locale settings see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html

d = {'Time': [datetime(2020, k, 15) for k in range(2,7)],
      'value': np.random.rand(5)}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
print(df.info())
print(df["Time"].dt.strftime("%a %H:%M"))

fig = px.line(df, y="value", x="Time")
fig.update_xaxes(
    tickformat="%a\n%H:%M",
)
fig.show()
```

gives me the following output on the console:

```
('de_DE', 'UTF-8')
        Time     value
0 2020-02-15  0.541681
1 2020-03-15  0.639813
2 2020-04-15  0.127375
3 2020-05-15  0.019197
4 2020-06-15  0.617402
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------  --------------  -----         
 0   Time    5 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   value   5 non-null      float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(1)
memory usage: 208.0 bytes
None
0    Sa 00:00
1    So 00:00
2    Mi 00:00
3    Fr 00:00
4    Mo 00:00
Name: Time, dtype: object
```

and the following diagram:
[image: plotly failing]

I already searched a lot but nothing worked (I know I could convert the timestamps to strings before passing them to plotly, but that's no good style), so has anyone suggestions what's going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: There are many tips in [Python plotly: Dates in other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361113/python-plotly-dates-in-other-languages). How about using a graph object, for example, to convert x-axis tick marks from existing data? `fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(mode='lines', x=[d.strftime('%a\n%H:%M') for d in df['Time']], y=df['value']))`

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I already set the locale in the code and converting the data to strings isn't nice since for the plotting lib data should be in a readable format to work on it/process it. By converting useful data -> string lots of information gets lost. And since plotly can do the dateformatting it should do so

Comment: [Additional information](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-get-plotly-to-use-the-set-locale/43499/15). In the words of the developer, the localization feature of plotly.js is not available. The workaround is to use the string and category axes.

Comment: Thanks for digging into this and sharing the thread. Well then I'll have no other choice than using strings for now and just wait for the localization option come to plotly-py. EDIT: Please consider writing an answer even though it is just the information that it's not possible up to now. I for my part searched a pretty long time until finding this. (and of course the bounty is still open ^^)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can find at this time, Plotly does not seem to change date formats, etc. when changing locales. The only way to deal with this seems to be to convert strings. The basis for this answer comes from the [community](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-get-plotly-to-use-the-set-locale/43499/15). The developer's comments are as of July 2021, so it is possible that this will be improved in the future. Also, my response may help other respondents to get a solution to this issue.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from datetime import datetime
import locale

#Get information on the actual locale setting:
print(locale.getlocale())

#Set locale for another country:
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE.UTF-8') 
# this sets the date time formats to Germany; there are many other options for currency, numbers etc.
# for any other locale settings see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html

d = {'Time': [datetime(2020, k, 15) for k in range(2,7)],
      'value': np.random.rand(5)}
df=pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
print(df.info())
print(df["Time"].dt.strftime("%a %H:%M"))

#fig = px.line(df, y="value", x="Time")
# Update
fig = go.Figure(go.Scatter(mode='lines', x=[d.strftime('%a\n%H:%M') for d in df['Time']], y=df['value']))
#fig.update_xaxes(tickformat="%a\n%H:%M",)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions to this problem suggest converting the date data for your plot to  string data instead. In [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69578922/865169) it does not really work to convert the time axis to a text label axis, because it for example loses information about the correct spacing between dates especially if your dates are not uniformly spaced.
As of version 5.14, what you can do instead is to manipulate the axis labels generated by Plotly by using the `labelalias` property. You can see [my other answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77216202/865169) for a tiny example how.